# Unhandled exception at 0x01221316 in testcamcalib.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00cf6000

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to trace lines using two cameras. Everything works fine until Canny Edge detection.

After `Canny` the program shows an error of memory location the same as in my title saying:

> Unhandled exception at 0x01221316 in testcamcalib.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00cf6000.

The pointer points at:

```
float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
```

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
//initializing camera and allocate memory to load the video stream from camera 
cv::VideoCapture camera0(1);
cv::VideoCapture camera1(0);

if( !camera0.isOpened() ) return 1;
if( !camera1.isOpened() ) return 1;

while(true) {
    //capture and retrieve each frames of the video sequentially, one frame at time will be displayed 
    // capture from 1st camera
    Mat edges0, edges1, dst0, dst1, cdst0, cdst1;
    cv::Mat3b frame0;
    camera0 >> frame0;
    // Performing edge detection on camera 1
    cvtColor(frame0, edges0, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges0, edges0, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
    Canny(edges0, dst0, 0, 30, 3);
     vector<Vec2f> lines;
    // detect lines
    HoughLines(dst0, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 150, 0, 0 );

    // draw lines
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
        line( cdst0, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    //capturing frames from second camera
    cv::Mat3b frame1;
    camera1 >> frame1;
    // performing edge detection on camera 2
    cvtColor(frame1, edges1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(edges1, edges1, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
    Canny(edges1, dst1, 0, 30, 3);
    // detect lines
    HoughLines(dst1, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 150, 0, 0 );

    // draw lines
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
        line( cdst1, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    }


    cv::imshow("edges0", cdst0);
    cv::imshow("edges1", cdst1);

    //wait for 40 milliseconds
    int c = cvWaitKey(30);

    //exit the loop if user press "Esif(27 == char(c)) breakc" key  (ASCII value of "Esc" is 27) 
    ;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to debug your code. Maybe there is a problem with the second dimension of `lines`. `lines[i][0]` or `lines[i][1]` could be not valid. You can put this two statements in separate lines and debug it to know more about the problem.